# file doesn't exist after saving with tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I saved my model using `tf.train.Saver('./model.ckpt')`, when I went to the local directory, I have found files named `model.ckpt.index`, `model.ckpt.meta` and `model.ckpt.data-00000-of-00001`, but not `model.ckpt`. As a consequence, I wasn't able to restore the model. Anyone know if i did anything wrong? Here's my code

```
class autoencoder(object):
    def __init__(self, network_architecture, learning_rate=0.001, regularization_constant=1):
        self.network_arch = network_architecture
        self.X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, network_architecture['n_input']])
        self.c = tf.Variable(regularization_constant, dtype=tf.float32)

        self._initialize_weights()
        self._build_graph()

        self.cost, self.optimizer = self._cost_optimizer(learning_rate)

        init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
        self.saver = tf.train.Saver()

        self.sess = tf.Session()
        self.sess.run(init)

   ...

    def save(self, path):
        self.saver.save(self.sess, path)

    def load(self, path):
        self.saver.restore(self.sess, path)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *.meta file contains your MetaGraph, and you can import it with:

```
saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph("model.ckpt.meta")
```

Then you can restore the graph's variables.

```
saver.restore(sess, "model.ckpt")
```

You can save additional model data to the metagraph by calling `tf.train.export_meta_graph`.

Alternatively, you can store your application's model using a SavedModel, which can contain multiple MetaGraphs. The documentation is [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/saved_model).

Comment: The solution works. Thought I did follow the documentation's first two references on save and restore, was the example on the restore tutorial wrong then?

Comment: It's a little confusing. The `saver.restore` method looks like it accepts the name of a specific file, but it actually accepts the "path where parameters were previously saved."